# Why does typeahead.js ignore spacebar presses?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm using the [AngularJS wrapper for typeahead.js](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) to add autocomplete functionality to an input field. It works well, except that I can't type spaces in the field; when I press the space bar, there's no space added to the input field.

This is different from the behavior in [this demo](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). I'm not seeing any Javascript errors either.

I'm using [UI Bootstrap 0.7](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for AngularJS and version 0.9.3 of typeahead.js. It's a Ruby on Rails 4 project.

I'm guessing that something is intercepting those key presses, but I'm not sure how to go about figuring out where that happens.

Comment: Since you're already including it in you project, why don't you use the typeahead plugin of ui.bootstrap (which is not showing this issue)?

Comment: @domokun I didn't realize that ui.bootstrap came with a completely Angular version of typeahead.js (rather than just a wrapper). It will take a bit of thinking to convert my code, but that's OK.

Comment: Actually it's not the `typeahead.js` lib, but it's the tipeahead plugin of Twitter Bootstrap entirely written in pure Angular, and it works quite well